# How do I solve the Ponytail puzzle?

Tags: the-looker

There's a room on the castle walls with a TV displaying a Braid parody called *Ponytail: "Thanks a Lot, Mac" Edition*. I'm able to draw lines on the screen indicating it's some kind of puzzle. Sometimes the game rewinds like Braid and the lines erase themselves, but I don't know what makes this happen.

How do I solve the Ponytail puzzle?

[image: title screen for ponytail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "solve" the ponytail puzzle by drawing a line between the S and the E. However, the line will always rewind to "unsolve" itself as a reference to Braid. There are no achievements or in-game progression associated with this puzzle.